What does BS EN 1150 certification of cycling jackets actually require re fluoresence and sizing?
The REMA document "Selection and Use of High Visibility Clothing for Non-Professional Use"
states among other things:

clothing must have a combination of fluorescent material for daytime visibility and reflective material for night-time and low light conditions


the garment MUST have a permanent label that states [...] The size of the garment (giving the height of the wearer, not just Small, Medium or Large)


Even for a small adult (158cm tall – 5ft 2in) a garment must incorporate a total of at least 0.32 m² of visible fluorescent material

I don't see many cycling items claiming this certification but two I have seen are:



Endura Urban Luminite EN1150 Waterproof Jacket
Decathlon BTWIN 500 Waterproof City Cycling Jacket - Navy









"Stand out from any angle. This waterproof cycling jacket is EN 1150 certified for day and night visibility. The hood can go over or under your helmet. EN 1150-certified nighttime visibility."



Neither (on their website) appear to provide any information on height (although it may be on the garment label).
The Decathlon does not (to my eye) have any fluorescent material at all.
The REMA document also states:

Unfortunately, despite the best endeavours of Trading Standards, there have been an increasing number of instances of clothing being falsely labelled as complying to the standard when it does not.

Is height information and fluorescent material actually required?
Do these two jackets comply?

I believe blue flourescent exists but I can't find any examples

Maybe its under the hood?  Unlikely, given how easy that spot would be to obscure.

@Criggie and 0.32 m² is not a small area (a touch under 57cm by 57cm)

@jhnc blue fluorescent isn't very fluorescent, even though it's a light blue.  This isn't it.  Fluorescence needs short-wavelength light to excite it, resulting in longer wavelengths being emitted.  For blue, that means only UV excitation, while the common fluorescent colours used in hi vis clothing are readily excited by blue (and in some cases green) light.  There just isn't enough UV in daylight to get blue to fluoresce very well, compared to yellow or orange

The first document you linked to also says "Fluorescent material can be yellow, green, orange, red or pink (including a combination of these)"

The product description contradicts itself. The sentence This waterproof cycling jacket is EN 1150 certified for day and night visibility suggests a full compliance to EN1150, but the next sentence EN 1150-certified nighttime visibility suggests that they only comply to the nighttime requirements.
Without having the full text of the norm, it's only possible to make assumptions, but it's reasonable to assume that daytime requirements are about fluorescent elements, nighttime requirements about reflective elements. So if the norm allows a partial compliance, this jacket may be indeed be compliant for nighttime only.

I've got a retroreflective jacket that claimed to meet a standard (and the number 1150 is familiar).  It had no fluorescent parts at all and is really bad for visibility against on dull days.  It also had strongly worded warnings not to modify it.  So I cut out the lining, along with the label full of warnings, improved the ventilation, and added a big back pocket with a storm flap made of fluorescent fabric.  More visible, but not longer compliant!

@jhnc note that the jacket you linked seems discontinued (not available for sale in Belgium). The new version (540) is less ambiguous on that topic, and only claims a nighttime certification.

good point - I hadn't noticed the "out of stock" on the decathlon page. but the endura one is definitely still being sold - seeing it and trying to find out what EN 1150 is was what prompted the question

being 6'3" tall, I like knowing about height information for other reasons (especially trouser length)

It seems that BS EN 1150:1999 was "withdrawn" in 2020 and superseded by BS EN 17353:2020. So I feel that any company promoting their products as meeting EN 1150 (instead of a current standard) is being disingenuous.
Although the former document costs hundreds of pounds to read, someone has placed a copy of the latter online at: https://www.en17353.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/BS-EN-17353-2020-Protective-clothing-Enhanced-visibility-equipment-for-medium-risk-situations-Test-methods-and-requirements.pdf

heights defined: ≤140cm / >140cm
three applications:

type A - daylight
type B - dark conditions
type AB - daylight + twilight + dark conditions


fluorescent not required for type B
"combined performance material" allowed instead of fluorescent or retroreflective
colour of fluorescent / combined performance material shall be yellow-green, yellow, yellow-orange, orange, orange-red, red, or pink
garments to be marked with:

name of manufacturer and address
number and year of the standard
type of equipment
symbol indicative of daylight and/or dark conditions of use


marking shall be on the product itself if possible, otherwise can be on attached label or "smallest packaging unit"

So, if the new standard does not deviate significantly from the withdrawn one, the Endura could likely be compliant as type AB and the Decathlon as type B.

Note sure that a certification to a standard is automatically revoked if the standard is superseded. But certification bodies are certainly not allowed to certify against a expired standard.

@Rеnаud it wouldn't surprise me if the endura jacket has been around since before the standard was withdrawn (it's a pity the wayback machine is under attack)

@Rеnаud It isn't automatically revoked, the standards body (CEN) specifies a date of withdrawal (DOW) of the previous standard. That isn't legally binding in itself, the European Commission needs to sign off on a Date Of Cessation Of Presumption Of Conformity Of the Superseded Standard (DOCOPOCOSS), which usually matches the DOW, though there's the possibility of extensions (happened a lot around COVID).

@user71659 thanks, I'm learning a lot (btw, I think Renaud's "Note" was meant to be "Not")

@jhnc correct, it's "not", but I noticed the mistake too late.
